# get url address for current spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get url address of current Spreadsheet by script without fixed address like this

```js
let curURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mCcmko-FvmTTJn8RDhlfWE0AZYPKlUnskqlc4-eYrJ4/edit?usp=sharing";
```

I tried to use this

let curURL = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

but I got empty value. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit?usp=sharing`, if you are using the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
let curURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() + "?usp=sharing";
```

- If you are not required to use `?usp=sharing`, please remove it.
- If your script is not container-bound script, how about the following script?

  ```
    const spreadsheetId = "###";
    let curURL = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/edit?usp=sharing`;
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl)

Comment: thank you very much! All your helps are very usefull))

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.